# UICollectionView insets / layout

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewflowlayout

[image]

How can I create that layout or I should play with collectionView insets?

Comment: You should look into creating a custom layout.

Comment: try to learn from this. 
https://medium.com/@tigraniskandaryan/custom-collection-view-layout-its-not-that-hard-to-create-6a73bcb8fb6e